# unable to shift pages from homepage to about page

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-generic-views

I am trying to create a small web application with django and I am a novice in this I am trying to create a homepage and a about button on homepage that reloads the page to about page

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple App</title>
<h1> Testing the simple app</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/about/">About </a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my about.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple App</title>
<h1> Testing the simple app</h1>
</head>
<body>

  This is the about page
</body>
</html>
```

This is my views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=None)

# Add this view
class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"
```

and urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from homepage import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^about/$',views.AboutPageView.as_view()),
]
```

However when i click on about button nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `urls.py` you can directly tell the Generic template view the name of the layout to use like this:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),
    path("about/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name="about" ]
```

Using named urls is better than directly coding the url, as they may change in the future.

Then in homepage.html refer to it as:

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
```

## Update:

If you can't use `path` and want to use `url`:

```
url(r'^$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),
url(r'^about/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name="about"),
```

Comment: When I have changed it, I am getting a NoReverseMatch found error

'about.html' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Comment: Check that you added `name="about"` in urls.py

Comment: I am not using path, as I use django<2 version so do you think this has something to do with the page not going to about.html ? Can i use the same urls.py you suggested but with url in the place of path ?

Comment: Thank you. It works!

For now this wil be enough to build up my basic skills however i have an assignment to make use of forms and database to store and access data. If i have any trouble with that, I would be grateful if you could assist me with that as well.